# Don't manually type cross-reference name

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    \label{thm}
    blahblah
\end{theorem}

Theorem~\ref{thm} states blahblah.

\end{document}
```

The problem here is that I have to manually type `Theorem~`. Almost always I have to type some name (Theorem, Lemma, Figure, etc.), which LaTeX can generate by itself in the point of definition. Is there a way to make latex write `Theorem~` (and others) by itself?

```
\smartref{thm} states blahblah.
```

I don't want

```
\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}
```

, since I'll have to define similar macros for other types.

It's completely possible that I miss something obvious, but I had no success in googling.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you're looking for the `cleveref` package and `\Cref{thm} states blahblah.`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, thank you very much! Seems to work  exactly like I want. By any chance, are you aware of any side effects / compatibility issues?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, never mind, this doc seems to cover it: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf

Comment: Other than the fact it should be the last package to be loaded, none that I know of. The package it pretty good :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have two main options: `\cref` (provided by the `cleveref` package) and `\autoref` (provided by the `hyperref` package).

Aside: If you don't want to make the cross-references into hyperlinks to their linked-to objects, just write `\Cref*{...}` and `\autoref*{...}` instead of `\Cref{...}` and `\autoref{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% 1. load 'hyperref' after `amsthm` but before 'cleveref' 
% 2. execute all `\newtheorem` statements *after* loading `cleveref`
\usepackage{amsthm} % or: \usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:bla} blah blah \end{theorem}

\Cref{thm:bla} states that \dots

As shown in \autoref{thm:bla}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! `autoref` doesn't seem to work for Lemmas: https://pastebin.com/3fzMxTSS

Comment: @dyukha - For theorem-like objects (such as `lemma`) whose labels are not yet defined by the `hyperref` package, just add an instruction such as `\newcommand\lemmaautorefname{Lemma}`, in the preamble.